# Word 2010: expand a control to fill its table cell

Tags: ms-word, controls

I have a table cell of fixed large size, and in it is nothing but a Plain Text Content Control, whose default placeholder text "Click here to enter text" takes up only a small portion of that table cell.

The problem is that if the user clicks anywhere in the cell but outside of the control's placeholder text, then starts typing, the entered text will not be part of the control and will not be subject to the control's style or any other control properties.

So - other than adding a lot of dummy characters to the placeholder text, which doesn't seem to be predictable in its word-wrap behavior, is there a way to make the control's placeholder text (or, in general, its click-boundary) fill the entire table cell?

**UPDATE**  actually there were some carriage returns after the control that I was not aware of; after deleting those, clicking anywhere in the cell *as long as the x coordinate if the click is greater than or equal to the leftmost x coordinate of the control* will edit the control text value as desired.  If you click leftward of the control, you will end up editing whatever fixed text exists to the left of the control, i.e. a fixed text label.  Still strange.  The workaround here was to split cells for all multi line text entry areas, such that the label is on its own cell, and the control is now at the leftmost edge of its cell.

Answer (score 0):

Content controls do not support something like expanding to the surrounding container. They will always use only the space that is required to render their content.

If you want to prevent users from clicking and typing text outside of the control, you could use the following approach:

- Put a rich text content control around your table/table row/cell
- Put the plain text content control as a nested content control in the table cell (the plain text content control must be non-vanishing for this to work)
- Make the outer content control read-only

Now the only thing the user is allowed to edit is the inner plain text content control. The downside of this approach is that your document now contains areas that are locked. This has an impact on usability, first, because, it may not be obvious to the user why certain areas cannot be modified, and second, because a lot of standard actions do no longer work if part of the selection is locked (e.g. Select All > Update ToC).

Comment: Interesting, thanks, please see upate to the question.  I will try just protecting the fixed text labels.  Is there a way to make a fixed text label part of the control, so that the control and it's label are always at the leftmost edge and the label will not accidentally be edited?